# Component speed isn't working?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

My code has been doing fine, but whenever you click the restart button, the speed of the main component grows over amount of clicks. Is there a way to fix that (to **reload** the page without *actually* reloading it, if you know what I mean)? Thanks to someone who finds a correct answer, I'll be sure to accept it :)

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Allan' rel='stlesheet'>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
      <style>
        canvas {
          border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
          background-color: #f1f1f1;
        }
    
        button.restart {
          position: absolute;
          left: 532px;
          top: 13px;
          padding: 3px 3px 0px 3px;
          background-color: #ffffffff;
          border-width: 1px;
          opacity: 0.4;
        }
    
        img.image {
          opacity: 0.4;
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body onload="startGame()">
      <script>
    
        var myGamePiece;
        var myObstacle;
        var myBlockPadl;
        var myBlockPadlI;
        var myBlockPadlII;
        var myBlockPadr;
        var myBlockPadrI;
        var myBlockPadu;
        var myBlockPaduI;
        var myBlockPaduII;
        var myBlockPadb;
        var myBlockPadbI;
        var emptyValue;
        var emptyValueI;
        var emptyhr;
        var emptyhrI;
        var emptyhrII;
        var emptyhrIII;
        var colorfill;
        var colorfillI;
        var colorfillII;
        var colorfillIII;
        var colorfillIV;
        var colorfillV;
        var colorfillVI;
        var colorfillVII;
        var colorfillVIII;
        var colorfillIX;
        var transitionBlock;
        var blockTransition;
    
        function startGame() {
          myGamePiece = new component(40, 40, "#00ff00ff", 50, 140);
          myObstacle = new component(80, 37, "#cf0000ff", 240, 0);
          myBlockPadl = new component(40, 80, "#7e3f00", 0, 120);
          myBlockPadlI = new component(40, 120, "#000000ff", 0, 0);
          myBlockPadlII = new component(40, 120, "#000000ff", 0, 200);
          myBlockPadr = new component(40, 117, "#000000ff", 520, 0);
          myBlockPadrI = new component(40, 117, "#000000ff", 520, 203);
          myBlockPadu = new component(40, 1, "#ffffffff", 520, 119);
          myBlockPaduI = new component(200, 40, "#000000ff", 40, 0);
          myBlockPaduII = new component(200, 40, "#000000ff", 320, 0);
          myBlockPadb = new component(40, 1, "#ffffffff", 520, 200);
          myBlockPadbI = new component(480, 40, "#000000ff", 40, 280);
          emptyValue = new component(40, 1, "#ffffffff", 0, 119);
          emptyValueI = new component(40, 1, "#ffffffff", 0, 200);
          emptyhr = new component(1, 80, "#ffffffff", 39, 40);
          emptyhrI = new component(1, 80, "#ffffffff", 39, 200);
          emptyhrII = new component(1, 80, "#ffffffff", 520, 200);
          emptyhrIII = new component(1, 80, "#ffffffff", 520, 40);
          colorfill = new component(78, 2, "#000000ff", 521, 117);
          colorfillI = new component(78, 2, "#000000ff", 521, 201);
          colorfillII = new component(10, 10, "#000000ff", 248, 5);
          colorfillIII = new component(10, 10, "#000000ff", 266, 5);
          colorfillIV = new component(10, 10, "#000000ff", 284, 5);
          colorfillV = new component(10, 10, "#000000ff", 302, 5);
          colorfillVI = new component(10, 10, "#000000ff", 248, 20);
          colorfillVII = new component(10, 10, "#000000ff", 266, 20);
          colorfillVIII = new component(10, 10, "#000000ff", 284, 20);
          colorfillIX = new component(10, 10, "#000000ff", 302, 20);
          transitionBlock = new component(10, 80, "#f1f1f1ff", 590, 120);
          blockTransition = new component(10, 80, "#f1f1f1ff", -40, 120);
          myGameArea.start();
        }
    
        var myGameArea = {
          canvas: document.createElement("canvas"),
          start: function () {
            this.canvas.width = 560;
            this.canvas.height = 320;
            this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
            document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
            this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
            window.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
              myGameArea.key = e.keyCode;
            })
            window.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
              myGameArea.key = false;
            })
          },
          clear: function () {
            this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
          },
          stop: function () {
            clearInterval(this.interval);
            ctx.fillStyle = "red";
            ctx.font = "80px Georgia";
            ctx.fillText("You died", 125, 120);
          }
        }
    
        function component(width, height, color, x, y) {
          this.width = width;
          this.height = height;
          this.speedX = 0;
          this.speedY = 0;
          this.x = x;
          this.y = y;
          this.update = function () {
            ctx = myGameArea.context;
            ctx.fillStyle = color;
            ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
          }
          this.crashWith = function (otherobj) {
            var myleft = this.x;
            var myright = this.x + (this.width);
            var mytop = this.y;
            var mybottom = this.y + (this.height);
            var otherleft = otherobj.x;
            var otherright = otherobj.x + (otherobj.width);
            var othertop = otherobj.y;
            var otherbottom = otherobj.y + (otherobj.height);
            var crash = true;
            if ((mybottom < othertop) || (mytop > otherbottom) || (myright < otherleft) || (myleft > otherright)) {
              crash = false;
            }
            return crash;
          }
          this.crashWithBlockl = function (otherbp) {
            var mesleft = this.x;
            var mesright = this.x + (this.width);
            var mestop = this.y;
            var mesbottom = this.y + (this.height);
            var othersleft = otherbp.x;
            var othersright = otherbp.x + (otherbp.width);
            var otherstop = otherbp.y;
            var othersbottom = otherbp.y + (otherbp.height);
            var crashBlock = true;
            if ((mesbottom < otherstop) || (mestop > othersbottom) || (mesright < othersleft) || (mesleft > othersright)) {
              crashBlock = false;
            }
            return crashBlock;
          }
        }
    
        function updateGameArea() {
          if (myGamePiece.crashWith(myObstacle)) {
            myGameArea.stop();
          } else if (myGamePiece.crashWithBlockl(myBlockPadl) || myGamePiece.crashWithBlockl(myBlockPadlI) || myGamePiece.crashWithBlockl(myBlockPadlII)) {
            myGamePiece.x = myGamePiece.x + 0.25;
            myGamePiece.update();
          } else if (myGamePiece.crashWithBlockl(myBlockPadr) || myGamePiece.crashWithBlockl(myBlockPadrI)) {
            myGamePiece.x = myGamePiece.x - 0.25;
            myGamePiece.update();
          } else if (myGamePiece.crashWithBlockl(myBlockPadu) || myGamePiece.crashWithBlockl(myBlockPaduI) || myGamePiece.crashWithBlockl(myBlockPaduII)) {
            myGamePiece.y = myGamePiece.y + 0.25;
            //Always remember that the Y+ and the Y- are switched!!!
            myGamePiece.update();
          } else if (myGamePiece.crashWithBlockl(myBlockPadb) || myGamePiece.crashWithBlockl(myBlockPadbI)) {
            myGamePiece.y = myGamePiece.y - 0.25;
            //Always remember that the Y+ and the Y- are switched!!!
            myGamePiece.update();
          } else if (myGamePiece.crashWithBlockl(transitionBlock)) {
            myGamePiece.x = myGamePiece.x - 560;
            myObstacle.x = myObstacle.x - 560;
            myBlockPadl.x = myBlockPadl.x - 560;
            myBlockPadlI.x = myBlockPadlI.x - 560;
            myBlockPadlII.x = myBlockPadlII.x - 560;
            myBlockPadr.x = myBlockPadr.x - 560;
            myBlockPadrI.x = myBlockPadrI.x - 560;
            myBlockPadu.x = myBlockPadu.x - 560;
            myBlockPaduI.x = myBlockPaduI.x - 560;
            myBlockPaduII.x = myBlockPaduII.x - 560;
            myBlockPadb.x = myBlockPadb.x - 560;
            myBlockPadbI.x = myBlockPadbI.x - 560
            emptyValue.x = emptyValue.x - 560;
            emptyValueI.x = emptyValueI.x - 560;
            emptyhr.x = emptyhr.x - 560;
            emptyhrI.x = emptyhrI.x - 560;
            emptyhrII.x = emptyhrII.x - 560;
            emptyhrIII.x = emptyhrIII.x - 560;
            colorfill.x = colorfill.x - 560;
            colorfillI.x = colorfillI.x - 560;
            colorfillII.x = colorfillII.x - 560;
            colorfillIII.x = colorfillIII.x - 560;
            colorfillIV.x = colorfillIV.x - 560;
            colorfillV.x = colorfillV.x - 560;
            colorfillVI.x = colorfillVI.x - 560;
            colorfillVII.x = colorfillVII.x - 560;
            colorfillVIII.x = colorfillVIII.x - 560;
            colorfillIX.x = colorfillIX.x - 560;
            //Always remember that the Y+ and the Y- are switched!!!
            myGamePiece.update();
            myObstacle.update();
            myBlockPadl.update();
            myBlockPadlI.update();
            myBlockPadlII.update();
            myBlockPadr.update();
            myBlockPadrI.update();
            myBlockPadu.update();
            myBlockPaduI.update();
            myBlockPaduII.update();
            myBlockPadb.update();
            myBlockPadbI.update();
            emptyValue.update();
            emptyValueI.update();
            emptyhr.update();
            emptyhrI.update();
            emptyhrII.update();
            emptyhrIII.update();
            colorfill.update();
            colorfillI.update();
            colorfillII.update();
            colorfillIII.update();
            colorfillIV.update();
            colorfillV.update();
            colorfillVI.update();
            colorfillVII.update();
            colorfillVIII.update();
            colorfillIX.update();
          } else if (myGamePiece.crashWithBlockl(blockTransition)) {
            myGamePiece.x = myGamePiece.x + 560;
            myObstacle.x = myObstacle.x + 560;
            myBlockPadl.x = myBlockPadl.x + 560;
            myBlockPadlI.x = myBlockPadlI.x + 560;
            myBlockPadlII.x = myBlockPadlII.x + 560;
            myBlockPadr.x = myBlockPadr.x + 560;
            myBlockPadrI.x = myBlockPadrI.x + 560;
            myBlockPadu.x = myBlockPadu.x + 560;
            myBlockPaduI.x = myBlockPaduI.x + 560;
            myBlockPaduII.x = myBlockPaduII.x + 560;
            myBlockPadb.x = myBlockPadb.x + 560;
            myBlockPadbI.x = myBlockPadbI.x + 560;
            emptyValue.x = emptyValue.x + 560;
            emptyValueI.x = emptyValueI.x + 560;
            emptyhr.x = emptyhr.x + 560;
            emptyhrI.x = emptyhrI.x + 560;
            emptyhrII.x = emptyhrII.x + 560;
            emptyhrIII.x = emptyhrIII.x + 560;
            colorfill.x = colorfill.x + 560;
            colorfillI.x = colorfillI.x + 560;
            colorfillII.x = colorfillII.x + 560;
            colorfillIII.x = colorfillIII.x + 560;
            colorfillIV.x = colorfillIV.x + 560;
            colorfillV.x = colorfillV.x + 560;
            colorfillVI.x = colorfillVI.x + 560;
            colorfillVII.x = colorfillVII.x + 560;
            colorfillVIII.x = colorfillVIII.x + 560;
            colorfillIX.x = colorfillIX.x + 560;
            myGamePiece.update();
            myObstacle.update();
            myBlockPadl.update();
            myBlockPadlI.update();
            myBlockPadlII.update();
            myBlockPadr.update();
            myBlockPadrI.update();
            myBlockPadu.update();
            myBlockPaduI.update();
            myBlockPaduII.update();
            myBlockPadb.update();
            myBlockPadbI.update();
            emptyValue.update();
            emptyValueI.update();
            emptyhr.update();
            emptyhrI.update();
            emptyhrII.update();
            emptyhrIII.update();
            colorfill.update();
            colorfillI.update();
            colorfillII.update();
            colorfillIII.update();
            colorfillIV.update();
            colorfillV.update();
            colorfillVI.update();
            colorfillVII.update();
            colorfillVIII.update();
            colorfillIX.update();
          } else {
            myGamePiece.update();
            myGameArea.clear();
            myObstacle.update();
            myBlockPadl.update();
            myBlockPadlI.update();
            myBlockPadlII.update();
            myBlockPadr.update();
            myBlockPadrI.update();
            myBlockPadu.update();
            myBlockPaduI.update();
            myBlockPaduII.update();
            myBlockPadb.update();
            myBlockPadbI.update();
            emptyValue.update();
            emptyValueI.update();
            emptyhr.update();
            emptyhrI.update();
            emptyhrII.update();
            emptyhrIII.update();
            colorfill.update();
            colorfillI.update();
            colorfillII.update();
            colorfillIII.update();
            colorfillIV.update();
            colorfillV.update();
            colorfillVI.update();
            colorfillVII.update();
            colorfillVIII.update();
            colorfillIX.update();
            transitionBlock.update();
            blockTransition.update();
            myGamePiece.x += myGamePiece.speedX;
            myGamePiece.y += myGamePiece.speedY;
          }
          //myGamePicec.update();myGamePiecemyGameArea.start();
          if (myGameArea.key && myGameArea.key == 37 || myGameArea.key && myGameArea.key == 65) { myGamePiece.speedX = -3; } else if (myGameArea.key && myGameArea.key == 39 || myGameArea.key && myGameArea.key == 68) { myGamePiece.speedX = 3; } else if (myGameArea.key && myGameArea.key == 38 || myGameArea.key && myGameArea.key == 87) { myGamePiece.speedY = -3; } else if (myGameArea.key && myGameArea.key == 40 || myGameArea.key && myGameArea.key == 83) { myGamePiece.speedY = 3; } else { myGamePiece.speedX = 0; myGamePiece.speedY = 0; }
          myGamePiece.update();
        }
      </script>
      <button class="restart" onclick='startGame()'><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-icon/rotate-arrow_318-1445.jpg" style="width: 25px; height: 25px;" class="image"></button>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are adding intervals multiple times, and not clearing them.  The simplest solution would be to check if `this.interval` exists, and if so, clear it before creating a new one.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Allan' rel='stlesheet'>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
      <style>
        canvas {
          border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
          background-color: #f1f1f1;
        }
    
        button.restart {
          position: absolute;
          left: 532px;
          top: 13px;
          padding: 3px 3px 0px 3px;
          background-color: #ffffffff;
          border-width: 1px;
          opacity: 0.4;
        }
    
        img.image {
          opacity: 0.4;
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body onload="startGame()">
      <script>
        var myGamePiece;
        var myObstacle;
        var myBlockPadl;
        var myBlockPadlI;
        var myBlockPadlII;
        var myBlockPadr;
        var myBlockPadrI;
        var myBlockPadu;
        var myBlockPaduI;
        var myBlockPaduII;
        var myBlockPadb;
        var myBlockPadbI;
        var emptyValue;
        var emptyValueI;
        var emptyhr;
        var emptyhrI;
        var emptyhrII;
        var emptyhrIII;
        var colorfill;
        var colorfillI;
        var colorfillII;
        var colorfillIII;
        var colorfillIV;
        var colorfillV;
        var colorfillVI;
        var colorfillVII;
        var colorfillVIII;
        var colorfillIX;
        var transitionBlock;
        var blockTransition;
    
        function startGame() {
          myGamePiece = new component(40, 40, "#00ff00ff", 50, 140);
          myObstacle = new component(80, 37, "#cf0000ff", 240, 0);
          myBlockPadl = new component(40, 80, "#7e3f00", 0, 120);
          myBlockPadlI = new component(40, 120, "#000000ff", 0, 0);
          myBlockPadlII = new component(40, 120, "#000000ff", 0, 200);
          myBlockPadr = new component(40, 117, "#000000ff", 520, 0);
          myBlockPadrI = new component(40, 117, "#000000ff", 520, 203);
          myBlockPadu = new component(40, 1, "#ffffffff", 520, 119);
          myBlockPaduI = new component(200, 40, "#000000ff", 40, 0);
          myBlockPaduII = new component(200, 40, "#000000ff", 320, 0);
          myBlockPadb = new component(40, 1, "#ffffffff", 520, 200);
          myBlockPadbI = new component(480, 40, "#000000ff", 40, 280);
          emptyValue = new component(40, 1, "#ffffffff", 0, 119);
          emptyValueI = new component(40, 1, "#ffffffff", 0, 200);
          emptyhr = new component(1, 80, "#ffffffff", 39, 40);
          emptyhrI = new component(1, 80, "#ffffffff", 39, 200);
          emptyhrII = new component(1, 80, "#ffffffff", 520, 200);
          emptyhrIII = new component(1, 80, "#ffffffff", 520, 40);
          colorfill = new component(78, 2, "#000000ff", 521, 117);
          colorfillI = new component(78, 2, "#000000ff", 521, 201);
          colorfillII = new component(10, 10, "#000000ff", 248, 5);
          colorfillIII = new component(10, 10, "#000000ff", 266, 5);
          colorfillIV = new component(10, 10, "#000000ff", 284, 5);
          colorfillV = new component(10, 10, "#000000ff", 302, 5);
          colorfillVI = new component(10, 10, "#000000ff", 248, 20);
          colorfillVII = new component(10, 10, "#000000ff", 266, 20);
          colorfillVIII = new component(10, 10, "#000000ff", 284, 20);
          colorfillIX = new component(10, 10, "#000000ff", 302, 20);
          transitionBlock = new component(10, 80, "#f1f1f1ff", 590, 120);
          blockTransition = new component(10, 80, "#f1f1f1ff", -40, 120);
          myGameArea.start();
        }
    
        var myGameArea = {
          canvas: document.createElement("canvas"),
          start: function () {
            this.canvas.width = 560;
            this.canvas.height = 320;
            this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
            document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
            if (this.interval) clearInterval(this.interval);
            this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
            window.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
              myGameArea.key = e.keyCode;
            })
            window.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
              myGameArea.key = false;
            })

          },
          clear: function () {
            this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
          },
          stop: function () {
            clearInterval(this.interval);
            ctx.fillStyle = "red";
            ctx.font = "80px Georgia";
            ctx.fillText("You died", 125, 120);
          }
        }
    
        function component(width, height, color, x, y) {
          this.width = width;
          this.height = height;
          this.speedX = 0;
          this.speedY = 0;
          this.x = x;
          this.y = y;
          this.update = function () {
            ctx = myGameArea.context;
            ctx.fillStyle = color;
            ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
          }
          this.crashWith = function (otherobj) {
            var myleft = this.x;
            var myright = this.x + (this.width);
            var mytop = this.y;
            var mybottom = this.y + (this.height);
            var otherleft = otherobj.x;
            var otherright = otherobj.x + (otherobj.width);
            var othertop = otherobj.y;
            var otherbottom = otherobj.y + (otherobj.height);
            var crash = true;
            if ((mybottom < othertop) || (mytop > otherbottom) || (myright < otherleft) || (myleft > otherright)) {
              crash = false;
            }
            return crash;
          }
          this.crashWithBlockl = function (otherbp) {
            var mesleft = this.x;
            var mesright = this.x + (this.width);
            var mestop = this.y;
            var mesbottom = this.y + (this.height);
            var othersleft = otherbp.x;
            var othersright = otherbp.x + (otherbp.width);
            var otherstop = otherbp.y;
            var othersbottom = otherbp.y + (otherbp.height);
            var crashBlock = true;
            if ((mesbottom < otherstop) || (mestop > othersbottom) || (mesright < othersleft) || (mesleft > othersright)) {
              crashBlock = false;
            }
            return crashBlock;
          }
        }
    
        function updateGameArea() {
          if (myGamePiece.crashWith(myObstacle)) {
            myGameArea.stop();
          } else if (myGamePiece.crashWithBlockl(myBlockPadl) || myGamePiece.crashWithBlockl(myBlockPadlI) || myGamePiece.crashWithBlockl(myBlockPadlII)) {
            myGamePiece.x = myGamePiece.x + 0.25;
            myGamePiece.update();
          } else if (myGamePiece.crashWithBlockl(myBlockPadr) || myGamePiece.crashWithBlockl(myBlockPadrI)) {
            myGamePiece.x = myGamePiece.x - 0.25;
            myGamePiece.update();
          } else if (myGamePiece.crashWithBlockl(myBlockPadu) || myGamePiece.crashWithBlockl(myBlockPaduI) || myGamePiece.crashWithBlockl(myBlockPaduII)) {
            myGamePiece.y = myGamePiece.y + 0.25;
            //Always remember that the Y+ and the Y- are switched!!!
            myGamePiece.update();
          } else if (myGamePiece.crashWithBlockl(myBlockPadb) || myGamePiece.crashWithBlockl(myBlockPadbI)) {
            myGamePiece.y = myGamePiece.y - 0.25;
            //Always remember that the Y+ and the Y- are switched!!!
            myGamePiece.update();
          } else if (myGamePiece.crashWithBlockl(transitionBlock)) {
            myGamePiece.x = myGamePiece.x - 560;
            myObstacle.x = myObstacle.x - 560;
            myBlockPadl.x = myBlockPadl.x - 560;
            myBlockPadlI.x = myBlockPadlI.x - 560;
            myBlockPadlII.x = myBlockPadlII.x - 560;
            myBlockPadr.x = myBlockPadr.x - 560;
            myBlockPadrI.x = myBlockPadrI.x - 560;
            myBlockPadu.x = myBlockPadu.x - 560;
            myBlockPaduI.x = myBlockPaduI.x - 560;
            myBlockPaduII.x = myBlockPaduII.x - 560;
            myBlockPadb.x = myBlockPadb.x - 560;
            myBlockPadbI.x = myBlockPadbI.x - 560
            emptyValue.x = emptyValue.x - 560;
            emptyValueI.x = emptyValueI.x - 560;
            emptyhr.x = emptyhr.x - 560;
            emptyhrI.x = emptyhrI.x - 560;
            emptyhrII.x = emptyhrII.x - 560;
            emptyhrIII.x = emptyhrIII.x - 560;
            colorfill.x = colorfill.x - 560;
            colorfillI.x = colorfillI.x - 560;
            colorfillII.x = colorfillII.x - 560;
            colorfillIII.x = colorfillIII.x - 560;
            colorfillIV.x = colorfillIV.x - 560;
            colorfillV.x = colorfillV.x - 560;
            colorfillVI.x = colorfillVI.x - 560;
            colorfillVII.x = colorfillVII.x - 560;
            colorfillVIII.x = colorfillVIII.x - 560;
            colorfillIX.x = colorfillIX.x - 560;
            //Always remember that the Y+ and the Y- are switched!!!
            myGamePiece.update();
            myObstacle.update();
            myBlockPadl.update();
            myBlockPadlI.update();
            myBlockPadlII.update();
            myBlockPadr.update();
            myBlockPadrI.update();
            myBlockPadu.update();
            myBlockPaduI.update();
            myBlockPaduII.update();
            myBlockPadb.update();
            myBlockPadbI.update();
            emptyValue.update();
            emptyValueI.update();
            emptyhr.update();
            emptyhrI.update();
            emptyhrII.update();
            emptyhrIII.update();
            colorfill.update();
            colorfillI.update();
            colorfillII.update();
            colorfillIII.update();
            colorfillIV.update();
            colorfillV.update();
            colorfillVI.update();
            colorfillVII.update();
            colorfillVIII.update();
            colorfillIX.update();
          } else if (myGamePiece.crashWithBlockl(blockTransition)) {
            myGamePiece.x = myGamePiece.x + 560;
            myObstacle.x = myObstacle.x + 560;
            myBlockPadl.x = myBlockPadl.x + 560;
            myBlockPadlI.x = myBlockPadlI.x + 560;
            myBlockPadlII.x = myBlockPadlII.x + 560;
            myBlockPadr.x = myBlockPadr.x + 560;
            myBlockPadrI.x = myBlockPadrI.x + 560;
            myBlockPadu.x = myBlockPadu.x + 560;
            myBlockPaduI.x = myBlockPaduI.x + 560;
            myBlockPaduII.x = myBlockPaduII.x + 560;
            myBlockPadb.x = myBlockPadb.x + 560;
            myBlockPadbI.x = myBlockPadbI.x + 560;
            emptyValue.x = emptyValue.x + 560;
            emptyValueI.x = emptyValueI.x + 560;
            emptyhr.x = emptyhr.x + 560;
            emptyhrI.x = emptyhrI.x + 560;
            emptyhrII.x = emptyhrII.x + 560;
            emptyhrIII.x = emptyhrIII.x + 560;
            colorfill.x = colorfill.x + 560;
            colorfillI.x = colorfillI.x + 560;
            colorfillII.x = colorfillII.x + 560;
            colorfillIII.x = colorfillIII.x + 560;
            colorfillIV.x = colorfillIV.x + 560;
            colorfillV.x = colorfillV.x + 560;
            colorfillVI.x = colorfillVI.x + 560;
            colorfillVII.x = colorfillVII.x + 560;
            colorfillVIII.x = colorfillVIII.x + 560;
            colorfillIX.x = colorfillIX.x + 560;
            myGamePiece.update();
            myObstacle.update();
            myBlockPadl.update();
            myBlockPadlI.update();
            myBlockPadlII.update();
            myBlockPadr.update();
            myBlockPadrI.update();
            myBlockPadu.update();
            myBlockPaduI.update();
            myBlockPaduII.update();
            myBlockPadb.update();
            myBlockPadbI.update();
            emptyValue.update();
            emptyValueI.update();
            emptyhr.update();
            emptyhrI.update();
            emptyhrII.update();
            emptyhrIII.update();
            colorfill.update();
            colorfillI.update();
            colorfillII.update();
            colorfillIII.update();
            colorfillIV.update();
            colorfillV.update();
            colorfillVI.update();
            colorfillVII.update();
            colorfillVIII.update();
            colorfillIX.update();
          } else {
            myGamePiece.update();
            myGameArea.clear();
            myObstacle.update();
            myBlockPadl.update();
            myBlockPadlI.update();
            myBlockPadlII.update();
            myBlockPadr.update();
            myBlockPadrI.update();
            myBlockPadu.update();
            myBlockPaduI.update();
            myBlockPaduII.update();
            myBlockPadb.update();
            myBlockPadbI.update();
            emptyValue.update();
            emptyValueI.update();
            emptyhr.update();
            emptyhrI.update();
            emptyhrII.update();
            emptyhrIII.update();
            colorfill.update();
            colorfillI.update();
            colorfillII.update();
            colorfillIII.update();
            colorfillIV.update();
            colorfillV.update();
            colorfillVI.update();
            colorfillVII.update();
            colorfillVIII.update();
            colorfillIX.update();
            transitionBlock.update();
            blockTransition.update();
            myGamePiece.x += myGamePiece.speedX;
            myGamePiece.y += myGamePiece.speedY;
          }
          //myGamePicec.update();myGamePiecemyGameArea.start();
          if (myGameArea.key && myGameArea.key == 37 || myGameArea.key && myGameArea.key == 65) { myGamePiece.speedX = -3; } else if (myGameArea.key && myGameArea.key == 39 || myGameArea.key && myGameArea.key == 68) { myGamePiece.speedX = 3; } else if (myGameArea.key && myGameArea.key == 38 || myGameArea.key && myGameArea.key == 87) { myGamePiece.speedY = -3; } else if (myGameArea.key && myGameArea.key == 40 || myGameArea.key && myGameArea.key == 83) { myGamePiece.speedY = 3; } else { myGamePiece.speedX = 0; myGamePiece.speedY = 0; }
          myGamePiece.update();
        }
      </script>
      <button class="restart" onclick='startGame()'><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-icon/rotate-arrow_318-1445.jpg" style="width: 25px; height: 25px;" class="image"></button>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: but it clears the canvas when it calls the `stop()` function and restart is clicked. how do you fix that?

Comment: nvm I just fixed it myself by adding `initialized = false;` to the `stop()` function.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same issue when I started game dev in JS. As it turns out, `setInterval` is kind of buggy, and just does this; i.e. if you set and clear multiple intervals in the same execution context, they often end up executing more often than needed. A coworker explained it to me years ago, I think it was because the browser queues up a whole bunch of iterations and just forgets/doesn't bother to cancel them when you clear the interval, and then when you start it again those iterations are still there, along with the new one. Or something. Don't quote me on that part.

Anyway, the solution is to use `window.requestAnimationFrame` instead. It'll take some reworking of your code, unfortunately, but it's much more reliable:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame

Comment: Thanks for the information, but I need something more simple. Thanks anyway.

Comment: No problem, also I totally missed the real issue that others have pointed out :P Still, in the long run you should definitely look into `requestAnimationFrame`. `setInterval` isn't entirely reliable to create a steady framerate, and it's not optimized to take advantage of the browser's own repaint cycle. Anyway, good luck with your game!

Answer (score 0):

When you do this:

```
this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
```

...you're only only clearing the interval when you call your `stop` function, not when you restart your game. So for every restart the game gets faster by having more and more calls to `updateGameArea` going on. Either set this interval only once if it's already been set, or make sure you clear the interval before you restart.